# I want to develop clickable <ul> with <li> if i click show correspondind child in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I want to develop Clickable List which have child list,

Like

```
Games|movies|songs|images|lyrics
```

If i click games

Games-->single player|multiplayer|online|offline
Movies-->science fiction|horrer|comedy
etc.

Likewise i want with clickable list hide and show type...in asp.net c#

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Please fix typo in your title, research what others have done on this site and show what you have tried so far. This will get you the best chance of help on this site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TreeView control, the best way to achieve this.

http://quickstarts.asp.net/quickstartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/navigation/treeview.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/d4fz6xk2(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: i don't want tree view i want  like this visit:https://www.nairabet.com/bets/category/2/2004/0 if i clik main-->Under/over games,first corner etc,then i click corner-->Under/over x corner,First corner like hide and show list..

Comment: So you can just use a <ul> <li></li> </ul> list with onclick define where you show and hide you data, i don't understand your question here ..